# SQL basic query question

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'll be the first one to admit my SQL skills are lacking. Now...

Let's say we've got a database table called Posts with three columns: Id, RootId, and DateTime.

What I'd like to do is get the last (by DateTime) 20 distinct RootId values.

Here's the caveat though: RootId may be NULL, in which case we should consider that record as distinct, and instead of NULL, Id should be returned.

What would the query be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select distinct top 20 isnull(rootid,id) from posts order by datetime desc`

Assuming this is for MS SQL Server

Comment: isnull(rootid,id) seems a bit odd. Why not isnull(rootid,0)?

Comment: Can you offer any ideas how I can take my request and translate it, mentally, into a query? You're correct in your answer.